# numpy returns nans for exponential. Pure Python returns correct result

Tags: python, numpy

I am really confused by this one. Maybe someone can clarify the outcome for me:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([ 1.97635114,  1.72790352,  1.51046621,  1.25543557,  1.01718594,
        0.77378732,  0.53452001,  0.29627038,  0.05802074, -0.18022889,
       -0.41847852])
e = -1.377404416

a**e
```

produces

`array([ 0.39126903,  0.47080342,  0.56661974,  0.73100461,  0.97680242, 1.42368231,  2.369756  ,  5.34193942, 50.47146058, nan, nan])`

```
[item**e for item in a]
```

gives me

`[0.39126902696026267, 0.4708034172873469, 0.5666197367017416, 0.7310046117775049, 0.9768024208132248,
 1.4236823077174863, 2.369756002432608, 5.341939422216064,
 50.47146057971127, nan, nan]`

BUT

```
-0.41847852**e
```

yields

```
-3.3197780173988067
```

Why is numpy not able to calculate the exponential of these two numbers ?

Comment: Might be related to the overflow as answered in this question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/367564/python-computing-likelihood-causing-exp-overflow

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Roots of negative numbers are not defined in real numbers. What python gives is the following: `-(0.41847852**e)` because of the operator precedence. Try with parenthesis `(-0.41847852)**e` :

`>>> (-1.247220271970189+3.0765837674262926j)`

It gives a complex number. That is why numpy computes them as `nan`. If you create numpy array with `dtype='complex'`, numpy can compute them as well.

Comment: Damn. Thank you. Even Wolfram Alpha tricked me. Basic calculus lecture was already way back

Answer (score 1):

While inside numpy, with your given array, only calculations with real values are made. Outside of numpy, Python does the calculations with complex values.

Note that `-0.41847852**e` is different from `(-0.41847852)**e`

Answer (score 1):

Pure Python is kind of fooling you here. It is not a real number for the negative roots is `a`. See below for a workaround if you would like one. It uses the `dtype=np.complex` to turn it into a complex number, the uses the `.real` to change it to what pure python is outputting.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([ 1.97635114,  1.72790352,  1.51046621,  1.25543557,  1.01718594,
        0.77378732,  0.53452001,  0.29627038,  0.05802074, -0.18022889,
       -0.41847852], dtype=np.complex)
e = -1.377404416

complexAnswer = a**e
realAnswer = complexAnswer.real
```